# Best practices to take input

Tags: arrays, go, io, stdout, stdin

I have written a `mergeSort` function, which sorted 1 million integers in 750ms, but it takes 9 seconds to take input.

This is how I have taken input to my slice, which is to be sorted.

code snippet:

```
array := make([]int,n)
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
    fmt.Scanf("%d",&array[i])
}
```

What I need is, an efficient way to take integers as input into a slice.
Input contains only integers, seperated by space or each integer in new-line.

Sample Input 1:

```
3
9
1
13
```

Sample Input 2:

`3    9    1    13`

If efficient solution is available for any one type of Input, it would suffice

Comment: What is the input you need to take? Is it a series of integers in their base 10 string representation. Are they signed or unsigned only? If you could post a sample that would be helpful.

Comment: Normal integers with base 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)
// inp is a variable in which we store our whole input
var inp []byte
// loc is used as index and remember till where we have seen our input
var loc int

func main() {
    // we read whole input and store it in inp and then append '\n', so
    // that we don't get any type index out of bound error, while 
    // scanning the last digit.
    inp, _ = ioutil.ReadAll(os.Stdin)
    inp = append(inp, '\n')
    // when ever scanInt is called, it will return single value of type int
    // usage:
    // n := scanInt()

}

func scanInt() (res int) {
    // skip if byte value doesn't belong to integer and break when it is
    // an integer
    for ; inp[loc] < 48 || inp[loc] > 57; loc++ {
    }
    // If it is an integer parse it completely else break return the result

    for ; inp[loc] > 47 && inp[loc] < 58 ; loc++ {
        res = (res << 1  ) + (res << 3) + int(inp[loc]-48)
    }
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that your input is space separated signed integers (in base 10), try the following:

```
s := bufio.NewScanner(os.StdIn)
s.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
i := 0
for s.Scan() && i < n {
    dest[i], _ = strconv.ParseInt(s.Text(), 10, 64)
    i++
}
```

This shows with a quick benchmark to be about 5 times faster than using `fmt.Scanf`. It could probably be further optimised by writing a custom split function that did not worry about parsing UTF-8 runes and simply split on `' '`.